# How to change file extensions in Xcode 4.3 iOS?

Tags: ios, file, xcode4.3, file-extension

My idea: syncing music without wifi or bluetooth. Its a work around to use camera connection kit to copy files to and from ipad without JAILBREAKING!First I get the the files I want , then I compress them into a zip file. Then I want to rename the extension JPG, so the iPad can recognize the file. Then I copy it to my sd card, then use camera connection kit to connect it to my iPad.

I wanted my app to copy the entire jpg form dcim so that I can change the file extension back to zip,then extract it to retrieve my files.

But so far I have only found a way to copy the file/jpg into my app but now I need to change the file extension back to zip, then export it to another app to be unextracted to retrieve my file.

Ps: I just need to figure out how to change file extensions in the app and export it!

Comment: Why all of the hacking? How about just using what Apple provides. I doubt that Apple would allow an App that circumvents their APIs and products.

Comment: "All the hacking"?  He's just tricking the file system, it's not hacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to change file extensions, because iOS doesn't support file renaming.  Just duplicate the file and write it to a path that contains the zip extension:

```
//get the documents directory
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//append the name of the file in jpg form
NSString *jpgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.jpg"];

//check if the file exists (completely unnecessary).
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:jpgPath]) {
    //get new resource path with different extension
    NSString *resourcePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.zip"];
    //copy it over
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:jpgPath toPath:resourcePath error:&error];
}
```